# HttpClient in async/sync implementation returns WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm having a problem with async to sync implementation of HttpClient.

```
Id = 8, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

I know what I'm doing is probably a bad practice and it would be ideal to make all the path async, but that's a request that the company is making me, so I have to do like this.

Project is build in NET Standard 1.1, to be used as a NuGet package and to be compatible with Framework and Core as well.

Here's my main client construction...

```
private static HttpClient _client;
private static Uri _baseAddress;
private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore };

public Client() { }

private Client(string baseUrl, Config config)
{
    _baseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

    _client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(config.Timeout) };

    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", config.Token);
}

private Client _paymentClient;
private Client _mainClient;

public Client Create(bool payment, Config config = null)
{
    if (!payment)
    {
        _mainClient = _mainClient ?? new Client("https://api.address.com/", config);
        return _mainClient;
    }

    _paymentClient = _paymentClient ?? new Client("https://payment.address.com/", config);
    return _paymentClient;
}

public void Dispose() => _client.Dispose();

private static async Task<T> Send<T>(HttpMethod method, string url, object data = null)
{
    var uri = new UriBuilder(_baseAddress);
        uri.Path += url;

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri.Uri);

    if (data != null)
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, _settings), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    T result = default;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            if (response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json")
            {
                var responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<T>>(content, _settings);

                if (responseObj.HasError)
                    throw new Safe2PayException(responseObj.ErrorCode, responseObj.Error);

                responseObj.ResponseDetail = result;
            }
        }
        else throw new Exception((int) response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode);

    request.Dispose();
    response.Dispose();

    return result;
}
```

And the `Send<T>` method is supposed to be a general treatment to process the request and response, wrapped on generic calls like this:

```
internal Task<T> Get<T>(string url) => Send<T>(HttpMethod.Get, url);

//OR even async...

internal async Task<T> Get<T>(string url) => await Send<T>(HttpMethod.Get, url);
```

Which are called like this, to send and receive data..

```
private Client Client { get; }

public CheckoutRequest(Config config) => Client = new Client().Create(true, config);

public object Credit(Transaction transaction)
{
    var response = Client.Post<Transaction>("v2/Payment", transaction);
    return response;
}
```

My problem is that the client is always getting me a `WaitingfForActivation` or even `Running` or `WaitingToRun`, doesn't matter if I change it to...

```
Task.Run(() => Send<T>(HttpMethod.Get, url));
//or
Task.Run(() => Send<T>(HttpMethod.Get, url).Result);
//or
Task.Run(async () => await Send<T>(HttpMethod.Get, url));
//or
Task.Run(async () => await Send<T>(HttpMethod.Get, url).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

I've been trying to find what I'm doing wrong, tried to change all the awaits, but I'm not being sucessful with this, so any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why have you got .ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: @AzharKhorasany It didn't made any difference for the task completion at all, but using it on client calls made it at least enters at WaitingForActivation. Without it, it returns the Running or even WaitingToRun status. I'm new at this, so I'm trying to look at examples of this implementation, but I haven't found much about that sync/async usage...

Comment: Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocks is a dangerous practice. You would have to use ConfigureAwait(false) for every await in the transitive closure of all methods called by the blocking code, including all third- and second-party code. Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlock is at best just a hack.

Comment: In this line: var response = Client.Post<Transaction>("v2/Payment", transaction); how is the call executed behind? Is it await Send<Transaction>(Method.Post, ...)? Why is your Client.Post not async/await?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany I removed all ConfigureAwait from the methods and changed the POST call to async/await, but the return is the same WaitingForActivation. The call on the final usage of the method must be made SYNCHRONOUSLY, so there's my main problem. If I turn it all to async/await, method works and provides the expected result. Is there any way that I can make it work on both ways when it's called?

Comment: Felipe, I know that you have got the answer now but on my previous comment I mentioned the post should be async so naturally when you call it you should be using await (which is actually the answer :))

Comment: @Felipe Do you have a habit of asking questions, getting a good answer, and then deleting the question? That's grounds for being banned from the site, just to warn you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57692613/62600

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
public object Credit(Transaction transaction)
{
    var response = Client.Post<Transaction>("v2/Payment", transaction);
    return response;
}
```

You didn't show your code for `Post<T>()`, but I assume it's also an `async Task<T>` method, which means `response` is a `Task<T>` and your code is basically doing this:

1. Start a task.
2. Return a description of the incomplete task.

When I assume this is really what you want:

1. Start the task.
2. Wait for the task to complete.
3. Return the result of the task.

Ideally, this should be an `async` method, and you can `await` the task:

```
public async Task<object> Credit(Transaction transaction)
{
    var response = await Client.Post<Transaction>("v2/Payment", transaction);
    return response;
}
```

If you *absolutely must* wait for the task synchronously (there are very few reasons to need to) then you can use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`:

```
public object Credit(Transaction transaction)
{
    var response = Client.Post<Transaction>("v2/Payment", transaction).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return response;
}
```

The main benefit of `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `.Result` is that, in the case of exceptions, it will throw the *actual* exception instead of an `AggregateException`.

Also, you can make your `Create()` method `static`:

```
public static Client Create(bool payment, Config config = null)
```

Then you don't need to initialize the class just to call it:

```
public CheckoutRequest(Config config) => Client = Client.Create(true, config);
```

*Update:* If you want `async` and non-async versions of the same method, you can follow the same standard that Microsoft uses and name the `async` method with the `Async` suffix. The non-async version can just call the async version. For example:

```
public async Task<object> CreditAsync(Transaction transaction)
{
    var response = await Client.Post<Transaction>("v2/Payment", transaction);
    return response;
}

public object Credit(Transaction transaction)
{
    return CreditAsync(transaction).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: Using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` solved the problem! Thank you very much! If it's not asking too much, I'd like to keep the `Credit()` implementation async to be awaitable, but is there any way that I could change it to call it either sync or async? I mean just like `Credit(transaction)` or `await Credit(transaction)` which doesn't require too many modifications or a new method? Thanks again.

Comment: No, you can't, because C# doesn't allow you (for good reason) to have two methods with the same name and same parameters that return a different type. But you can have an `async` method called `CreditAsync()`, and then just make your non-async `Credit()` method call `CreditAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is a bad code using until this implementation with until `Post` being async and having it wrapped in both sync `Credit` and async `CreditAsync` for example? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, sorry. But I updated my answer with an example of async and non-async versions of the same method.

Comment: @Felipe - `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` should absolutely be avoided in a library.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hi! Sorry for asking such thing, but as a beginner, would you mind if I ask you to explain why, please? That was the only solution that I found so far that worked for the call to be completed, but if there's something else that I can do to work as I was asked to mount it, I would really appreciate any tip. Thanks.

Comment: .Wait() may block some app types. Your lib shouldn't impose that on a caller. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/

Comment: Agreed. Ideally, everything should be async. There is rarely a reason to have to use a synchronous version. (as the article points out - you can just leave it to the person using the library to deal with making it synchronous if they *really* need it - or rewrite a *truly* synchronous version of the method that doesn't use any async calls)